# how can I load my .el file only while editing python code

Tags: python, emacs

I have collected a list of emacs customizations in a file `my-python-setup.el`. How can I ensure that emacs will first load `python-mode` and then load this library only when I'm editing python files?

I've tried putting

```
(load-library "my-python-setup")
```

in my .emacs file, but that loads these customizations for all kinds of files.

These customizations are on top of python-mode, and the value of `auto-mode-alist` currently is `("\\.py\\'" . python-mode)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm by no means an Emacs expert, but I think you could just stick add a `python-mode-hook` function and load your library in there.  Something like:

```
;; define your hook function
(defun python-mode-setup ()
  (message "Custom python hook run")
  (load-library "my-python-setup"))

;; install your hook so it is called when python-mode is invoked
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'python-mode-setup)
```

Here is my personal `python-mode-hook`, for example:

```
(defun python-mode-setup ()
  (setq python-indent-offset 4
        python-indent 4
        ;; turn off indentation guessing in various python modes
        python-guess-indent nil
        python-indent-guess-indent-offset nil
        py-smart-indentation nil
        ;; fix mark-defun in new python.el
        python-use-beginning-of-innermost-defun t))
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'python-mode-setup)
```

Comment: Will, this didn't work for me, but using eval-after-load worked.  (eval-after-load "python-mode"
  '(progn
     ;; Do whatever you need to do here, it will only get executed after python-mode.el has loaded
    load-library "my-python-setup")))

Answer (score 1):

If you only want your code to be loaded when you edit python code, you may want to consider sticking your lisp code in your own major-mode which extends python mode.

```
(define-derived-mode 'my-python-mode 'python-mode "MyPy" 
"A customized version of python-mode"

... here goes your code ...

)
```

Then you'll have to configure emacs to load `'my-python-mode` instead of `python-mode` by adjusting `auto-mode-alist`.

Comment: I found this to be the best way. Strokes my ego too, having a mode named after myself :)

Comment: I don't know what I was thinking when I proposed that answer. `eval-after-load` is definitely the standard (and better) way to go.